# Failed to fetch the job titles from indeed using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to grab job titles from the search result of a webpage, indeed.com, using the requests module. Here is the [link](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=motorcycle%20mechanic&l=New%20York%2C%20NY) to that webpage where I wish to fetch the job titles.

The following is how I've already tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs"
params={
    'q': 'motorcycle mechanic',
    'l': 'New York, NY'
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
def get_job_titles(url):
    res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    link_list = []
    for item in soup.select("#mosaic-jobResults td.resultContent h2 > a > span[id^='jobTitle']"):
        link_list.append(item.get("href"))
    return link_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for title in get_job_titles(link):
        print(title)
```

When I run the script, I always get status 403. How can I get the job titles from that webpage using the requests module?

Comment: Have you tried Selenium?

Answer (score 4):

The page `https://www.indeed.com/jobs` is protected by `CloudFlare`.

```
import requests

params={
    'q': 'motorcycle mechanic',
    'l': 'New York, NY'
}

http_headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
response = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs', headers=http_headers, params=params, allow_redirects=True,
                   verify=True, timeout=30)
```

output `print(response.headers)`

Note the *'Server': 'cloudflare'* in the output.

```
{'Date': 'Sat, 01 Apr 2023 18:42:55 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'close', 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 
'require-corp', 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Permissions-Policy': 
'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),
geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),
payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),
usb=()', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Cache-Control': 
'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 
'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': '__cf_bm=afTsbfjJKeoN7yqVDI7bGjYTFhaF_QEDC9mCtkjT1Js-1680374575-0-AQJ5H4x6T28fONNVrM8Fh2nYeq6G8RB3+L/vxbSJwWTzIjPb0CeR/HO1AsKx9GRj6dLZz+ZHZ/Oc8om0NMQ+/YM=; 
path=/; expires=Sat, 01-Apr-23 19:12:55 GMT; domain=.indeed.com; HttpOnly; Secure; 
SameSite=None', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 
'CF-RAY': '7b12f98b0847adb9-ATL', 'Content-Encoding': 'br', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; 
ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'}
```

output `print(response.text)` snippets

These snippets indicated that the page is throwing a `Cloudflare challenge` for your `Python request`.

```
 <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>


trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=7b130075eea3ad6b');

 cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=7b130075eea3ad6b';
```

I would recommend using [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) to scrape the site.  I don't want to post the exact code that I used to bypass the `CloudFlare` protection for [indeed.com](https://www.indeed.com)

```
# .bypass() is a function based on the link I provided.

soup = Cloudflare('https://www.indeed.com/jobs').bypass()
table_results = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'resultContent'})
for item in table_results:
    link = item.find('span')
    print(link.attrs)
    # {'title': 'Auto Mechanic (Diesel)', 'id': 'jobTitle-9d7ba98aa6ce1036'}
    # {'title': 'Motorcycle Mechanic A,B OR C', 'id': 'jobTitle-a91f7c5e2d1c0a53'}
    # {'title': 'NEW VEHICLE SET UP MECHANIC', 'id': 'jobTitle-cbe3a30bbf3e415d'}
    # {'title': 'Motorcycle Mechanic', 'id': 'jobTitle-8736df00befc62ab'}
    # {'title': 'Mechanic', 'id': 'jobTitle-cf8a92124f5fe421'}
```

This [site](https://morioh.com/p/f285991e3a31) provides the basic details on how to use `cloudscraper`, which will allow you to bypass the `CloudFlare` protection.

While `Cloudscraper` works most of the time it might be better to use a paid service, such as [zenrows](https://www.zenrows.com/) to bypass the `CloudFlare` protection for `https://www.indeed.com/jobs`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am wrong, but it does not seem possible to scrape the job titles without executing the JS that renders the respective HTML.

I used my browser's Dev Tools, to check if the website made a GET request for a file with the data you want, but there was no such request.

I used `requests` to send the GET request to the page's [URL](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=motorcycle%20mechanic&l=New%20York%2C%20NY) with the `User-Agent` header and all of the GET request's cookies. The response was an HTML file with the message "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue". I also tried sending the request with all of headers and then without the cookie header; both responses were a byte string.

Due to this I think you will need to use `selenium` or `playwright`.

##### Code:

(I did not include my cookies for privacy. You can get your own with your browser's Dev Tools)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def view_html(url, my_headers=None, my_cookies=None):
    res = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers, cookies=my_cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
    print(res.content)
    print()
    print(soup.prettify())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    h = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Host': 'www.indeed.com',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'TE': 'trailers'
    }

    url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=motorcycle%20mechanic&l=New%20York%2C%20NY"
    view_html(url, h)
```

##### Output I received when all the headers (including the cookies) were used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <title>
   Just a moment...
  </title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body class="no-js">
  <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
   <div class="main-content">
    <noscript>
     <div id="challenge-error-title">
      <div class="h2">
       <span class="icon-wrapper">
        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon">
        </div>
       </span>
       <span id="challenge-error-text">
        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </noscript>
    <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=7ae4ebc3addb024e')">
    </div>
    <form action="/jobs?q=motorcycle%20mechanic&amp;l=New%20York%2C%20NY&amp;__cf_chl_f_tk=zIdr3DHmAJEASpAwEGxbIEtQmt5wL_BF3Yqs2ajK6Tg-1679891666-0-gaNycGzNCxA" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
     <input name="md" type="hidden" value="I9Py8hlouSMytpiZY5RC15bVHtkglArAOJhDSLlZ0w4-1679891666-0-AUAyCZMpA1ufMJS2Xm-l7-qV8mKgUPs47V9ZDsPd8nkfsXw6IJb7GbEKMebi0J5s5-bQyKpn4REwwOz6pc8ZRFXo728tfb3-nR5KCNz0Za58ndbkYk8lebn2zmUH9xPaC44PaHol0bp2fRU8SsQIaJxzpcrfwkE7weOPwGNK25S15T1EU8RVHmQqpNXPVIyxz5yPbZxXOAPaAhCvX9sEoqtxBbx1W413ks4H3bTvC2I8eUKiySi_-8oXBLn14BGwgsa1BN8QIVFXabuesHhLRgpW5eX7gvm5eDAbLHSOUJ7pmGV8AAJhEzAnSKrsf6EY6fkxo8BlGVbqcZHkVbImgzhOUgdSxEHtnW4_DKYk4SMFfj3oPShf_jKvvioPhDbVjdPneiarW5yRS_Bmcy_nnyzPdabMo-8FjG-s_bgn00tzsEoLVYr2nDp_yJbM2HIbK_3p-PtLsPy9TJ9RMPzKrdHp6YpmsykKXZr2_lx_pLGEIbKuSOvblkuZ7j8GV9jGTMPfvdkdJUse_AOHaRCHZSGbDTCtLjC-wIfQQNXLWcufQjIVYTaLidsh3gCMkWceD37_lUSQDTp6udZhT0aUuwDOmYMVCV6eyLbPMfjp4i_pDGrXh6U2B55e8PIX_db_LGS2f1Nt1XhvdHzQObnnCbiNX8aMKL6IAQQekElS5QZCJCjjtu4NRE8aEjh2x8KXBFbYYjMOSc8zEga6RzB_0FtKMuDgguMWIoewCV-S7vdUh0MtCQKULKFu9x20DorhF-pSqyQMwCfSVSO2p1ARc6Dofwo8t8wINR86wMJoJSJonjctytcBzQID0oKPJLZJG4K__xnOgL2Lf0-1NoMhAsxFHGcJi2_Gljsv03jneOizIkwxo2mmI26A-nJ9cI5dK684XisuuG7PnBhSpLpoYZoJPvc9HkkCl4rJKKE6T2p0UT3wQ4KNdZwAgdyVVuQ5BElh9qG5Sq9eiBYvccrzejxa4pl04IFl8zmHYF6YFUOhjhC2P7tLBPBal_Le1Fvz2YHSv8gwial8Su03nMmaugTt3COeQT1wKUGaXff5n-KTYa9wA6p9l1QqupFW5XvkpeVR3BOLRvK2RN6os3IuAUY4wxyCY9IVLd3QO7AB-VkQazUVpgwdDvLVBVaHgZAakh_NEPX3KlS3s8_dTUqJ9yp4aJoCDuOLOdk4wnNrkMPa6nOeviDQcK5066i_yGD8Ege1ss_vJ5d583vuKnZ5J0Fi1JK8JOoJO8SVJ7oIZTLixZmgzVlrMFmaqP5P0Exb2pT--WCQQsHF9jyLq40_Mt5HWpMO5zCMZJK-tK96WfmxAsIdE7R46O1nkEkap2SXeGyBwT95xjixkzZAOguKJe_eUB5gDt9rKc65JLRL3Vv1pu6YSU-gFmw5VZEzHzsiQ_iOlybBKQhd37RXb3aBsxkxE5lOM8UjcHj1zRU3fy3SRS1OEHKkgCX_07qzH0-7rnCBoyaK4Ci-c88YYfDgx910k1RWOiPcsBW5-WNup528wYvBBPzEH3bbQcG5ZkMLPI63OWhM8ExAcXHjRSYpKyXdWMdpdTgPDNMa87SBr-TE87nNURVGAEwKKdtbYv0Mg6IzjSqKW-3RQokIRTHtHjWCatz3Vl1K-xHznrzAE2Y7yOzvs4hN79ZOQSMcEcCPvEnGHbSNImcWSm97Qc4g5mPXr2t7KqTlcDZxvEzEPMvC5p6Efa2qIrR4HuccRJ35gvUypTVuIHByqHcNzntourd6y_-ra5fwOhWKIpsRsQwKciocn0Q23SwdM3HpMKio-t5bWYEKBeAFvmRvNTMhrqyOljQxaSUxd5qTQfqP1k0v4B9ish-zghMSGP-jjsb7PUS2xLQcJDkU_SbJodCUEfi_frtq9X-jkTlJJrCDWkTr-9ifk2kXB9dTa7wBrGsww5rDSFDuRAlvxLR9vV-csq-hHGcxoVnUojvMJikt-j0E8F_apdlgpRoYStDcGu992BJcHVu5n8SI-fK4rMsXAHEL-Dr5FCGowYeTCnLTBXAqnZv_NDzsIa6Y99mYZWY0u97sc9-UBWCRXBsy0-icc_9LI83BVpOdkUHQc62VbbEqjNRzMJU1GhaJMxGU6VxCg5lkQHR1p4Ssfgwe6U3JxW04SqlvWRR785kGtzhTzZ2mToNcG7h64-FVuHoHoWc864uIKqrK9By60W-aOI5soNEyI9TaFaeYIqvhkxIqkn56JETNmexeoOp7pPPx34PB5SnTb79E5Pa-fWvHxRwScJWXp-JOsvPbd3ws4LYw-tEzQEqUJ9MqMTm2FXJ44NX82ansO5tJyONdAxwr-8VWnYU3x6USelSwznYsIP3lSdq3x3KA71iMYyUxvhsVHo5qBR-4SWKtZvwKxW2inHD-LYRuRcwzKHvTiPA9qDaN-fqPwhOkiX4JpVed-_5gxc05xTVuJNa2rAdWWIbcbwIbwWYjcRqrf41FXa8sulx13qE8CksWF2SFBqtfQa9p5s89aa_NU_fwXKRawaXWa2js_n87ZE2wgetE6vk8_b9qx3kYOsZD4MgeLC_-idkcFvKy8Pk2FaYLVX8-rHNZ0l43DJa6blV4BaaLzi1QbR_Kl6XsTk0d1UgcU_zmY0caReNAx_sKY88zIU4B5CQR9JwhDm2lkzgmrxqOhcuHemA2-UB6Ti8wXRJRzi3yIxBuvtPL8ZvS2I9sAnFzQfJZzKpvTVoKkRSqsBHM8F0IcRXYcRIFuLvWPDX4NGeWOMjU3ALVy87ZVvtOvBoOQonwdZ4mrWQ"/>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```